# Powershell script that can be added to a release pipeline for fetching variables from key vault

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I want to use azure key vault secrets in azure devops release pipeline.could someone help me with powershell script in which I can define these variables and pass it in pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Powershell script that can be added to a release pipeline for fetching variables from key vault

You could configure a Variable Group to connect to an Azure Key Vault:

- Go to "`Pipelines`" and then "`Library`" and "`Add variable group`".
- Link secrets from an Azure key vault
- Configure a Pipeline to make use of the new Variable Group

Then, whatever variables you have in your variable group can be accessed from your build pipe as `$(VariableNameHere)` including the key vault.

You could check [the great document](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.